# CloudFormation can't update launch configuration - "Not authorized to perform this operation"

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a CloudFormation stack up and running and I'm trying to update it to make the instances bigger, but the update keeps failing, saying "You are not authorized to perform this operation" when attempting to change the Launch Configuration.

This shouldn't happen--I'm running a user that has full admin privileges for all services, and I used this user to create this very stack in the first place. What's going on here?

There is no defined role for this stack, I just let it auto-create an IAM role.

EDIT: I'm only having this problem in the US-East-1 region. In all other regions I can update my CloudFormation stacks without issue. This makes no sense, as I have the exact same settings in every stack in every region.

EDIT 2: This isn't just with CloudFormation.. I'm actually having this problem when attempting to create Launch Configurations directly as well.. when I try to create a new Launch Configuration in US-East-1 it says "Failed to create launch configuration; You are not authorized to perform this operation" but I can create new launch configurations in all other regions without issue. Furthermore, using the Simulate Policy tool, it shows that I should be able to do this no problem.

Comment: Is your template running under an assigned Role?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein no I just let it auto-create one

Comment: Auto-create? Normally the stack runs under your own permissions, unless you "choose a role". The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-launchconfig.html) does show that InstanceType of a Launch Configuration can be changed.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I didn't choose a role.. so it automatically created a new one for the instances. That's how CloudFormation has always worked when I've used it...